# Получение строки значений из groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Есть DataFrameGroupby со следующими данными:

```
                       last  vol
datetime                        
2013-07-23 10:00:00  112450   49
2013-07-23 10:00:00  112440   67
2013-07-23 10:00:00  112430   93
2013-07-23 10:00:00  112420   52
2013-07-23 10:00:00  112410   63

                       last  vol
datetime                        
2013-07-23 10:01:00  112690   17
2013-07-23 10:01:00  112680   59
2013-07-23 10:01:00  112670  226
2013-07-23 10:01:00  112660  184
2013-07-23 10:01:00  112650  289
```

Сгруппированные по уровню индекса:

```
blocks_group = datetime_group.groupby(level=0)
```

Как получить целую строку из каждой группы с максимальным значением, а не только значения столбца `vol`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [47]: df
Out[47]:
                       last  vol
datetime
2018-08-31 10:00:00  112450   49
2018-08-31 10:00:00  112440   67
2018-08-31 10:00:00  112430   93
2018-08-31 10:00:00  112420   52
2018-08-31 10:00:00  112410   63
2018-08-31 10:01:00  112690   17
2018-08-31 10:01:00  112680   59
2018-08-31 10:01:00  112670  226
2018-08-31 10:01:00  112660  184
2018-08-31 10:01:00  112650  289
```

Решение:

```
In [48]: df.groupby(level=0, as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1, 'vol'))
Out[48]:
                         last  vol
  datetime
0 2018-08-31 10:00:00  112430   93
1 2018-08-31 10:01:00  112650  289
```

Ещё один, менее идиоматичный, вариант:

```
In [51]: df.sort_values('vol').groupby(level=0).tail(1)
Out[51]:
                       last  vol
datetime
2018-08-31 10:00:00  112430   93
2018-08-31 10:01:00  112650  289
```